# Как сделать значение куки в виде массива и стоит ли так делать?

Tags: yii, php, cookie

В yii есть возможность быстро и просто создать куку со значением. Пример:

```
$cookie = new CHttpCookie('users',$model->id);
                    Yii::app()->request->cookies['users']=$cookie;
```

Вопрос вот в чем: если мне нужно хранить, к примеру, в куке id пользователей, то как правильно это организовать? Логика подсказывает, что значение куки должно быть примерно похоже на это "12, 23, 44, 11, 123". Если так, то как сделать такую строку и привязать ее к значению этой куки?

Comment: А зачем в куке хранить id пользователей?

Comment: К примеру, если пользователю, у которого хранится кука, надо выдавать список просмотренных им других пользователей в том случае, если он не авторизован.

Comment: если он не авторизован, то зачем ему что-то выдавать.

Comment: Странный вопрос, который не имеет отношения к моей задаче. id пользователей я привел для примера. Это может быть что угодно: id фотографий, товаров и т.д.

Comment: Ну, ответ такой - не храните в куке ничего, кроме идентификатора сессии (и то не обязательно), все остальное в самой сессии или webdb/localstorage.

Comment: Я не спрашивал, какие именно данные хранить или не хранить в куках. Меня интересует только способ, как можно в значение куки упаковать массив данных в том или ином виде.

Answer (score 1):

Значением куки может быть строка. Чтобы записывать в строку массив или объект, надо его сериализовать одним из способов. Например, [serialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php) или [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php).

[Ограничение на длину](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-27) одной куки: 4096 байт, включая название и атрибуты.